# Laravel 8: Route login not defined after redirection back from auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I just added this route group to `web.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::get('profile' , [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');
});
```

As you can see I have used the middleware `auth` so if I'm not logged in, it should be showing me the login page.

And I had also defined authentication routes manually:

```
Route::prefix('auth')->namespace('Auth')->middleware('guest')->group(function() {
    Route::get('login' , [LoginController::class, 'showLogin'])->name('auth.login');
    Route::post('login' , [LoginController::class, 'login']);
    Route::get('register' , [RegisterController::class, 'showRegister'])->name('auth.register');
    Route::post('register' , [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
});
```

So the route name of the login page is `auth.login` and I just added it to `Authenticate` middleware which is set to `auth` at `kernel.php`:

`'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,`

`Authenticate.php`:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('auth.login');
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem is whenever it should showing me the login page when not signed in, I get this error message:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route
> **[login] not defined.**

So what's going wrong here, how can I fix this error?

Comment: in `login.blade.php` you need to change `action="{{ route('login') }}"`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes it is already set to `action="{{ route('auth.login') }}"`, I can login properly, the only problem comes from this middleware redirection!

Comment: could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: try to gave route name ->name('login') instead of auth.login

Comment: Do you see the routes if you run `php artisan route:list`?

Answer (score 1):

### In `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('auth.login'));
}
```

Comment: you need to import this `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;`

Comment: Thanks man. But I get the same error: `Route [login] not defined.`

Comment: @kamleshPaul I also faced this error, do you have any more idea about this?

Comment: @KKKKKK probably you removed `login` route and used `auth` middleware `Authenticate.php`

Answer (score 1):

Just change this

```
Route::get('login' , [LoginController::class, 'showLogin'])->name('auth.login');
```

to this

```
Route::get('login' , [LoginController::class, 'showLogin'])->name('login');
```

> This sounds ridiculous but true. The reason is when you call login you call it with `auth.login` but Laravel knows only `login`. I had a similar issue and able to sort it by defining another route(GET).

[image: route]

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses `login` route somewhere for example in `\app\Http\Handler.php` therefore it's necessary to have login route. You can change your route name as `Abdulla Nilam` said before or If you don't want to change it, add this:

```
Route::get('/login/redirect', function () {
     return redirect(route('auth.login'));
})->name('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

( Laravel 8 ) **In App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('auth.login');
        }
    }
}
```

you can easily change "***login***" to "***auth.login***" !